# Short hand to pass boolean props to Vue component

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

In the Vue docs for components it says:

> Including the prop with no value will imply `true`:
>   `<blog-post favorited></blog-post>`

However, when I try it on my component, it doesn't work ([related fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kshep92/Ly95tv4a/)):

```
<!-- html -->
<div id="app">
  <test-component visible></test-component>
</div>

<template id="template">
  <span>open: {{ open }}; visible: {{ visible }}</span>
</template>

<!-- JS -->
const TestComponent = Vue.extend({
  template: '#template',
  props: ['visible'],
  data: function() {
    return { 'open': true }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    'test-component': TestComponent
  }
});
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would also expect it to work as it is, but it seems you need to specify the type of field in the props declaration:

```
props: {
    'visible': {
        type: Boolean
    }
}
```

This makes it work correctly

Comment: Looks like that does it. Alternative notation  `props: { visible: Boolean }` works as well. Thanks!